# Regex - Find Name With No Middle Initial

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm doing a query on an SQL database and need to write a regular expression to find names with no middle initial.

For example.

- Michael J. Fox - Should fail
- Michael J Fox - Should fail
- Michael Fox - Should pass

Full names in the database are stored in a single string for reference.

Comment: And if you had a full middle name, would that pass or fail?

Comment: So everybody assumes that between first name and last name there is always a single space, never 2 or more, never a tab, never a comma etc.?

Comment: Fair point on the spacing, but this is for a school assignment and the professor has given us the impression the data is sanitized to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
\w{2,} \w{2,}
```

two words, space separated, at least two chars each.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a rather simple one:

```
^([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z]+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach(for *MySql* query):

```
SELECT 
    fullname 
FROM
    table
WHERE
    fullname REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+$';
```

---

`[:alpha:]` - represents a character class that matches all *alphanumeric characters*

`[:space:]` - represents a character class that matches *Space, tab, newline, and carriage return*

Answer (score 1):

You can count space and filter out result like

where length('Michael J Fox')-length(replace('Michael J Fox',' ',''))<2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression.  How about this?

```
where name like '% %' and name not like '% % %'
```

This just looks for two spaces in the name.

If you really wanted just middle initials, then:

```
where name not like '% _ %' and name not like '% _. %'
```

Comment: `_` can be space... :-)

Answer (score 0):

the ^ operator looks for characters at the begining of the line and the \$ operator looks at the end of the line. this regex will look for exactly two words in a line that are at least two characters long.

^[a-zA-Z]{2,} [a-zA-Z]{2,}\$

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (name text);
insert into t values ('Michael J Fox');
insert into t values ('Michael J. Fox');
insert into t values ('Michael Fox');
insert into t values ('  Michael     Fox  ');
```

Allowing for leading and trailing spaces, and multiple spaces in between, but only two sets of non-space characters:

```
select name, name REGEXP '^ *[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ *$'
from t;
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/CFID40649

```
+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|        name         | name REGEXP '^ *[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ *$' |
+---------------------+----------------------------------+
| Michael J Fox       |                                0 |
| Michael J. Fox      |                                0 |
| Michael Fox         |                                1 |
|   Michael     Fox   |                                1 |
+---------------------+----------------------------------+
```